# I m feching data into firebase but when i reload page stops rendering

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-chrome, render

```
  function Chat() {
  const [input, setInput] = useState("");
  const [seed, setSeed] = useState("");
  const { roomId } = useParams();
  const [roomName, setRoomName] = useState("");
  const [messages, setMessages] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    if (roomId) {
      db.collection("rooms")
        .doc(roomId)
        .onSnapshot((snapshot) => setRoomName(snapshot.data().name));

      db.collection("rooms")
        .doc(roomId)
        .collection("messages")
        .orderBy("timestamp", "asc")
        .onSnapshot((snapshot) =>
          setMessages(snapshot.docs.map((doc) => doc.data()))
        );
    }
  }, [roomId]);

  useEffect(() => {
    setSeed(Math.floor(Math.random() * 5000));
  }, [roomId]);

  const sendMessage = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("you typed >>>", input);
    setInput("");
  };

  return (
    <div className="chat">
      <div className="chat__header">
        <Avatar
          alt="random"
          src={`https://avatars.dicebear.com/api/pixel-art/${seed}.svg`}
          sx={{ width: 38, height: 38 }}
        />
        <div className="chat__headerInfo">
          <h3>{roomName}</h3>
          <p>last seen at...</p>
        </div>
        <div className="chat__headerRight">
          <IconButton>
            <SearchIcon />
          </IconButton>
          <IconButton>
            <AttachFileIcon />
          </IconButton>
          <IconButton>
            <MoreVertIcon />
          </IconButton>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="chat__body">
        {messages.map((message) => (
          <p className={`chat__message ${true && "chat__reciever"}`}>
            <span className="chat__name">{message.name}</span>
            {message.message}
            <span className="chat__timestamp">
              {new Date(message.timestamp?.toDate()).toUTCString()}
            </span>
          </p>
        ))}
      </div>
      <div className="chat__footer">
        <InsertEmoticonIcon />
        <form>
          <input
            value={input}
            onChange={(e) => setInput(e.target.value)}
            type="text"
            placeholder="Type a message..."
          />
          <button onClick={sendMessage} type="submit">
            Send a message
          </button>
        </form>
        <MicIcon />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Chat;
```

i tryed to fix puting the isloading like you said but it was worse, maybe i ve done it wrong but it stoped rendering without the data pass to objects.

note that when i save this code
 `{messages.map((message) => ( <p className={`chat__message ${true && "chat__reciever"}`}> <span className="chat__name">{message.name}</span> {message.message} <span className="chat__timestamp"> {new Date(message.timestamp?.toDate()).toUTCString()} </span> </p> ))}` with localhost on it works well, but when i reload page and restart the app with the code saved it doesnt render

Answer (score 0):

if i change this statement  `const [messages, setMessages] = useState("");` to  `const [messages, setMessages] = useState([]);`  it works